# python graphic user interface

Tags: python, user-interface

I recently finished a big project i have been working on, and i am looking for a new challenge. I was thinking about making python play a game, and making it unbeatable. to do this, i need an easy way of entering the other players move, and i was thinking about something where i can create multiple buttons which the user can press. (for example: if i want to make tic tac toe i would want 9 individual buttons that are triggered by a mouse click, to get the input).

I have no idea if this is possible in python. i have seen multiple pages about this, but some pages have such a large amount of information on them that i don't know where to start.

thanks in advance for any answers,
Harm

Comment: What have you learned from digging through this information?

Comment: "I have no idea if this is possible" Searching your exact question title resulted in this top hit: https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming. Maybe start there?

Comment: Ignacio not much, as i'm very new to this it's not clear to me what all terms mean. I just need to know the basics, and all the information i can find is about the advanced stuff

Comment: Chris i know making a gui is possible, but i have know idea if the way i want to use it is possible.

Comment: The simplest, built-in library is `tkinter`, and obviously you can make clickable buttons.

Comment: thanks for the answer, after looking into tkinter i realised the question was kind of dumb, so i'm sorry for that ;p